# MATLAB interpolation and sorting points help required

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I successfully read the datum from a .trk file and parsed its header&body. Now I have to apply an interpolation. Before that, here is the information about my variables:

I have `tracks <1x110470 struct>`. Under the tracks struct, I have two vectors. They are `nPoints` and `matrix`. `nPoints` include the number of points exist in the vector `matrix`.

For example, if I select tracks(1,95607), nPoints=3 and matrix={(1.2323,1.4441,2.345),(2.333,4.555,4.123),(1.22,2.33,3.44)}

nPoints are not a fixed number. It can even be 100 etc. But matrix is a `nPoints*3` vector. I do always have 3 coordinates.

Now what I have to do is a basic interpolation like taking half of the boundaries and adding that new points. Let me assume, under tracks(1,2) I have three points a,b,c,d then I need to add points (a+b)/2 and (b+c)/2 and (c+d)/2.

First of all I could not even write a successfully algorithm that does this. Could you please help me? (Interpolation will be applied to all tracks. But I will not do any interpolation for example between tracks(1,1) and tracks(1,2) I will only apply it to the points inside the tracks and also, points in tracks are not sorted.)

Second, what I was wondering is that: is it possible to have an algorithm which does parametrized interpolation. What I mean is:

Assume that my points are: a,b

If parameter=1 then I want to only add (a+b)/2

If parameter=2 then I want to have also (a+(a+b)/2)/2 and ((a+b)/2)+b)/2 in addition to the parameters when parameter=1

..
..
..

I want it to go iterative like that. Is it possible?

Comment: have you looked into `help cell`

Comment: try to be a bit more brief and concise, you'll get more chance for a good answer -- note that people are picking answers from a list.. (just focus on what you wanna ask, your problem.)

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs what is most important for me is the second question: parametrized interpolation thing. Do you have an idea about it?

Comment: @Amadeus The point is being, that you have an interpolation thing thing, you have already gotten an answer which was as vague as your question. I think you could have an easy solution with some basic matrix operations, once you have made clear what you really want to achieve. Then I (and many others) could readily help with that "easy solution".

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs I am trying to create a neural map of brain and those points in the vector `matrix` are the points where neuron tracks pass through. However when I visualized them, I noticed that they are not condensed enough. Sometimes, there happens to be disconnections on a particular neuron track. Therefore I decided to use interpolation for a better visualization. However I did not decide on how much interpolation to be done. Therefore I want to make this process parametrized if it can be done. Could you help me? (I am sorry if my answer is still not clear.)

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs if you are going to edit the post, please fix it. There are plenty of things to fix here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really make out what "parameterized interpolation" you really want, I put here my best guess.

I guess that you wanna do at some point a `[a b c d]  -> [a (a+b)/2 b (b+c)/2 c (c+d)/2 d]` transformation, possibly with multiple iterations.

For that problem, my solution would be

```
ret = function interp(v, rounds)
    n=length(v);
    avg = (v(1:n-1)+v(2:n))./2;
    temp = [v(1:n-1); avg];
    ret = [temp(:), v(n)];
    if rounds>1
        ret = interp(ret, rounds-1);
    end
end
```

The `[a b c d]  -> [a (a+b)/2 b (b+c)/2 c (c+d)/2 d]` transformation is given by
`interp([a b c d], 1)`.

Other example: `interp([1 2], 2)` -> `[1 1.25 1.5 1.75 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/?as=1) and the official Matlab help (F1).